# Как запустить Python3 Anaconda из linux Mint?

Tags: python, linux, linux-mint, anaconda

Установил на систему Linux Mint пакет Python3.6 Anaconda, из терминала при вызове python запускается python 2,7, а при вызове python3 запускается python 3,5, Anaconda же идет с Python последней версии 3,6, но как ее запустить не понятно, установка произошла в рабочую папку пользователя

Answer (score 2):

Просто добавил Анаконду в переменную среду Линукса:
export PATH="/home/papa/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
После этого команда python3 запускает нужного питона.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в домашнем каталоге должна быть папка miniconda3(или anaconda3) в ней есть папка bin, в папке bin есть файл python3.
То есть запуск питона примерно такой(команда для терминала):

```
~/miniconda3/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

в терминале пишешь команду
$ anaconda-navigator

Если надо запустить только юпитер лаб, то поможет команда
$ jupyter lab

Если что, то я работаю в ALT linux